# How to decode the AOL Feedbag 1.1 file

Tags: c#-4.0, encryption, encoding

In AOL AIM 7, under the path "C:\Users\Prakash\AppData\Roaming\acccore\caches\users\UserA", there is a file "feedbag".

The file is not in text format. Its format is as shown in the picture below when opened in Notepad++.

[image]

How can we decode this information?

Feedbag file can be downloaded from the link below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6cirpFZgAoZXzNMR0llenFua00/view?usp=sharing

------------------ **update1**: on oct 18-----------------------------------------

It is found that the file feedbag is created ( or updated if that file already exists) only when AIM user is sing-in the AIM Instant Messenger. If any contact (buddy) goes offline or online, the file is not updated - this would be one of the great limitation in our code to find the exact online members of each Blast Group.

I sign-in in AIM IM using the account qaninjazz (display name is qaninjazz3). There is a blast group PTGrp and it has four members. Currently, only two members (qaninjazz and presenqa) are online.

(presenqa user was already signed-in in web browser iwantim.com before I sign-in in AIM IM)

I run the code against the neweset feedbag file created but it does not list any members of the PTGrp.
I have attached the output of this test here:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6cirpFZgAoZdV9PekxwdTJjQkk/view?usp=sharing

The code should have listed the online members of the PTGrp but it did not. May be, the AIM itself does not put the up-to date data in the file itself.

However, in the output screenshot, we can see that a member of Group for "age" and "NewAIMUsers".

But mr_parker is not online now - this would be a big question because we need only the online members.

"age" is the group that was created in the AIM so it is not blast group.

Based on all these information, I think that we cannot rely on the file feedbag for getting the online members of blast groups.

My basic requirement is to know the participants (online members) of the AIM Blast Group when the user chat on that group.

I am wondering if there is any AOL API or third party API or oscar API to find out the members of blast group in real time.

Please let me know if you want any further information.

Link for the feedbag file that was created on Oct18:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6cirpFZgAoZU254b0hCWTVwTkE/view?usp=sharing

Link for output file:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1LsNO4-kisjMGP8LtXdSddQC-DbYbfYo_D0WYsqvtgG8/edit?usp=sharing

------------------**update1**:---------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 2):

AOL Feedbag files usually contain information about an AIM buddy list.

The the following files give some insight on the wireformat file also references documents for the wire format for feedbag data -- and may help decode the data that follows the names (see comment about unknown data)

https://web.archive.org/web/20081224015759/http://dev.aol.com/aim/oscar/#FEEDBAG

I was able to figure out how to dump the names of the buddies and groups, buddies follow a group, with matching groupdId,  groupId == 0 isn't really a group, it contains other meta data about buddies or the buddy list app.

Sorry the code is in C, I don't have a C# environment.  Also keep in mind that the FEEDBAG file is in Network order, so you have to 'swap' the integer's byte order if you are on an Intel box

test.cpp

```
// BuddyList.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "stdint.h"
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <errno.h>
#define SWAP_UINT16(x) _byteswap_ushort(x)

char* asprintf(char* format, ...);
void dump_buffer(unsigned n, const char* buf);

char feedbag[] = "AOL Feedbag 1.1";

int main() {
    FILE *fp;

    // open the file
    fp = fopen("./feedbag", "rb");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        perror("Error while opening the file.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("sizeof feedbagstring %ld\n", sizeof(feedbag));

    // seek past file header AOL Feedbag 1.1<null><null>
    int offset = sizeof(feedbag) + 1;
    fseek(fp, offset, SEEK_SET);

    int16_t numberOfFeedbagItems = 0;

    // number of buddies
    fread(&numberOfFeedbagItems, 1, sizeof(numberOfFeedbagItems), fp);
    numberOfFeedbagItems = SWAP_UINT16(numberOfFeedbagItems);


    for (int ii = 0; ii < numberOfFeedbagItems; ii++) {

        // u16  2 bytes Unsigned two byte short
        // string16 u16 + data  Two byte length followed by that many bytes of data
        // tlvLBlock    u16 + data  Two byte length of elements, followed by that many bytes of elements

        // https://web.archive.org/web/20081224015759/http://dev.aol.com/aim/oscar/#FEEDBAG__Item   

        //This is a single Feedbag item.
        // Name     Type    Notes
        // name     string16    UTF8 string of the item's name; maximum length of 97 characters
        // groupId  u16 ID of the group of which the item is part
        // itemId   u16 ID inside the group; if 0 then this is the definition of the group
        // classId  u16 [Class: FEEDBAG__CLASS_IDS] ID of the class of which this item is a member
        // attributes   tlvLBlock   [Class: FEEDBAG__ATTRIBUTES] All the attributes for the item; a group must contain the ORDER attribute

        char* name = 0;
        uint16_t nameLen = 0;
        char* attributes = 0;
        uint16_t attributesLen = 0;
        uint16_t groupId, itemId, classId;

        fread(&nameLen, 1, sizeof(nameLen), fp);
        nameLen = SWAP_UINT16(nameLen);
        if (nameLen) {
            name = (char *)calloc(1, nameLen + 1);
            fread(name, 1, nameLen, fp);
        }

        //ID of the group of which the item is part
        fread(&groupId, 1, sizeof(groupId), fp);
        groupId = SWAP_UINT16(groupId);

        // ID inside the group; if 0 then this is the definition of the group
        fread(&itemId, 1, sizeof(itemId), fp);
        itemId = SWAP_UINT16(itemId);

        //FEEDBAG__CLASS_IDS
        //https://web.archive.org/web/20081224015759/http://dev.aol.com/aim/oscar/#FEEDBAG__CLASS_IDS
        fread(&classId, 1, sizeof(classId), fp);
        classId = SWAP_UINT16(classId);

        // variable length buffer
        fread(&attributesLen, 1, sizeof(attributesLen), fp);
        attributesLen = SWAP_UINT16(attributesLen);
        if (attributesLen) {
            // attributes   tlvLBlock   [Class: FEEDBAG__ATTRIBUTES] 
            // All the attributes for the item; a group must contain the ORDER attribute
            // https://web.archive.org/web/20081224015759/http://dev.aol.com/aim/oscar/#FEEDBAG__ATTRIBUTES
            attributes = (char *)calloc(1, attributesLen);
            fread(attributes, 1, attributesLen, fp);
        }


        if (groupId == 0 && itemId == 0) {
            printf("root: groupdId:%d itemId:%d classId:%d\n", groupId, itemId, classId);
        } else
        if (itemId != 0) {

            if (classId == 0) {
                if (name) {
                    printf("\n\tbuddy: %s groudId:%d itemId:%d classId:%d\n", name, groupId, itemId, classId);
                }
            }
            else if (name) {
                printf("\n\tdata: %s groudId:%d itemId:%d classId:%d\n", name, groupId, itemId, classId);
                //printf("\t\t hexdump:");
                //for (int ii = 0; ii < attributesLen; ii++) {
                //  printf("%02x", attributes[ii]);
                //}
                //printf("\n");
                dump_buffer(attributesLen, attributes);

            }
            else {
                name = "<unknown>";
                switch (classId) {
                case 5:
                    name = "Buddy List Preferences";
                    break;
                case 20:
                    name = "BART IDs; name is the BART Type";
                    break;
                case 38:
                    name = "??? classId(38)";
                    break;
                default:
                    name = asprintf("classId %d", classId);
                    break;
                }

                printf("\n\tdata: %s groupdId:%d itemId:%d classId:%d\n", name, groupId, itemId, classId);
            }
        }
        else if (classId == 1) {
            if (name == NULL) {
                name = "<unknown>";
            }
            printf("group: %s groupdId:%d itemId:%d classId:%d\n", name, groupId, itemId, classId);

        }
        else {

            printf("\nunknown: %s groupdId:%d itemId:%d classId:%d\n", name, groupId, itemId, classId);
        }
        if (nameLen) free(name);
        if (attributesLen) free(attributes);
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}

void dump_buffer(unsigned n, const char* buf)
{
    int on_this_line = 0;
    fputs("\n\t", stdout);
    while (n-- > 0) {
        fprintf(stdout, "%02X ", (unsigned char)*buf++);
        on_this_line += 1;
        if (on_this_line == 16 || n == 0) {
            int i;
            fputs(" ", stdout);
            for (i = on_this_line; i < 16; i++)
                fputs(" ", stdout);
            for (i = on_this_line; i > 0; i--)
                fputc(isprint((unsigned char)buf[-i]) ? (unsigned char)buf[-i] : '.', stdout);
            fputs("\n\t", stdout);
            on_this_line = 0;
        }
    }
    fputs("\n", stdout);
}

char* asprintf(char* format, ...) {

    char *ret = 0;

    if (!format) return 0;

    va_list args;
    va_start(args, format);
    int size = _vscprintf(format, args);

    if (size > 0) {
        size++; //for null
        ret = (char*)malloc(size + 2);
        if (ret) _vsnprintf(ret, size, format, args);
    }

    va_end(args);
    return ret;
}
```

Output

```
sizeof feedbagstring 16
root: groupdId:0 itemId:0 classId:1

    data: Buddy List Preferences groupdId:0 itemId:1 classId:5

    data: 0 groudId:0 itemId:2 classId:38

    00 67 00 04 55 0B B9 58 00 7A 00 04 00 00 81 72  .g..U..X.z.....r
    00 79 00 3C 67 85 6E A6 DC 6D 5E 51 01 32 B7 28  .y.<g.n..m^Q.2.(
    61 57 51 02 55 0B B9 58 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  aWQ.U..X........
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 6D 00 1B 74 65 78 74 2F 61 6F 6C 72 74 66 3B  .m..text/aolrtf;
    63 68 61 72 73 65 74 3D 22 75 74 66 2D 38 22   charset="utf-8"


    data: 1 groudId:0 itemId:3 classId:20

    00 D5 00 07 00 05 02 01 D2 04 72       ..........r


    data: prdpbgt-0v6amoovg@groupchat.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:4 classId:28

    00 65 00 08 70 72 65 73 65 6E 71 61 00 67 00 04  .e..presenqa.g..
    55 FA 59 38 01 4B 00 06 02 01 00 05 00 00 00 9D  U.Y8.K..........
    00 07 70 72 64 70 62 67 74 00 B0 00 09 50 72 65  ..prdpbgt....Pre
    73 65 6E 20 51 41 01 31 00 07 70 72 64 70 62 67  sen QA.1..prdpbg
    74                 t


    data: 1024 groudId:0 itemId:5 classId:20

    00 D5 00 07 00 05 2B 00 00 32 33       ......+..23


    data: classId 4 groupdId:0 itemId:6 classId:4

    data: classId 26 groupdId:0 itemId:7 classId:26

    data: Travolta Windows groudId:0 itemId:8 classId:54

    00 A0 00 04 53 85 C1 4C 00 A1 00 04 56 08 E5 49  ....S..L....V..I
    01 50 00 04 00 00 00 6D 01 53 00 04 00 00 00 51  .P.....m.S.....Q
    00 9F 00 04 00 00 00 E2 01 60 00 04 56 08 E5 CB  .........`..V...
    00 8C 00 04 53 85 C1 54 00 8F 00 04 53 85 C1 54  ....S..T....S..T
    00 A4 00 04 53 85 C1 4C 01 67 00 04 00 00 00 00  ....S..L.g......
    00 AF 00 02 40 02            ....@.


    data: Travolta Web groudId:0 itemId:9 classId:54

    00 A0 00 04 53 85 C1 55 00 A1 00 04 56 0C D5 48  ....S..U....V..H
    01 50 00 04 00 00 00 02 01 53 00 04 00 00 00 02  .P.......S......
    00 9F 00 04 00 00 00 0C 01 60 00 04 56 0C D5 EA  .........`..V...
    00 8C 00 04 53 85 C1 56 00 8F 00 04 53 85 C1 56  ....S..V....S..V
    00 A4 00 04 53 85 C1 4C 01 67 00 04 00 00 00 00  ....S..L.g......
    00 AF 00 02 00 02            ......


    data: classId 56 groupdId:0 itemId:10 classId:56

    data: presenqa groudId:0 itemId:11 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 56 04 E6 0C 01 31 00 09 50 72 65 73  ....V....1..Pres
    65 6E 20 51 41             en QA


    data: combinedService groudId:0 itemId:12 classId:44

    00 8B 00 04 55 64 38 A4 00 98 00 04 00 00 00 05  ....Ud8.........


    data: classId 29 groupdId:0 itemId:13 classId:29

    data: aolsystemmsg groudId:0 itemId:14 classId:51

    01 C9 00 04 55 DD 4D 5C 01 C7 00 04 55 DD 4D 5C  ....U.M\....U.M\


    data: testuser@gmail.com groudId:0 itemId:15 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 55 E4 2B 3D          ....U.+=


    data: 1234-0646kqn2j@groupchat.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:16 classId:28

    00 9D 00 04 31 32 33 34 00 B0 00 09 50 72 65 73  ....1234....Pres
    65 6E 20 51 41 00 67 00 04 56 09 0A 27 01 4B 00  en QA.g..V..'.K.
    06 02 01 00 05 00 00 01 31 00 04 31 32 33 34   ........1..1234


    data: aimNewTOS groudId:0 itemId:17 classId:57

    01 CC 00 04 53 F5 7A F1 01 CB 00 04 53 F5 7A F1  ....S.z.....S.z.
    00 B6 00 04 00 00 00 01 00 B9 00 0E 00 00 00 01  ................
    00 00 28 A0 00 00 00 01 00 00        ..(.......


    data: nirajb groudId:0 itemId:18 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 55 E4 2E CF 01 31 00 0B 45 64 69 74  ....U....1..Edit
    65 64 42 75 64 64 79           edBuddy


    data: techvortex-015bbktqu@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:19 classId:28

    00 65 00 00 00 67 00 04 55 E7 E5 30 01 4B 00 06  .e...g..U..0.K..
    02 01 00 05 00 00 00 9D 00 0A 74 65 63 68 76 6F  ..........techvo
    72 74 65 78 01 31 00 0A 54 65 63 68 56 6F 72 74  rtex.1..TechVort
    65 78                ex


    data: yashbajra groudId:0 itemId:20 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 55 E5 36 00 01 31 00 10 59 61 73 68  ....U.6..1..Yash
    20 42 61 6A 72 61 63 68 61 72 79 61       Bajracharya


    data: designers groudId:0 itemId:21 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 55 E5 2A FD 01 31 00 09 44 65 67 69  ....U.*..1..Degi
    6E 65 72 73 32             ners2


    data: techvortex-015bbktqu@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:22 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 56 04 D4 07          ....V...


    data: 1234-0646kqn2j@groupchat.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:23 classId:51



    data: devblast2-0ugeo2oi9@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:24 classId:28

    00 65 00 00 00 67 00 04 55 E8 2B 3C 01 4B 00 06  .e...g..U.+<.K..
    02 01 00 05 00 00 00 9D 00 09 64 65 76 62 6C 61  ..........devbla
    73 74 32 01 31 00 05 28 44 45 56 29      st2.1..(DEV)


    data: sovita.dahal@presensoft.com groudId:0 itemId:25 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 56 04 E3 D5 01 C9 00 04 56 0E 10 ED  ....V.......V...
    01 31 00 15 43 68 6F 77 69 74 61 28 45 64 69 74  .1..Chowita(Edit
    65 64 42 75 64 64 79 29 3A         edBuddy):


    data: bg02-07778u3le@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:26 classId:28

    00 65 00 00 00 67 00 04 55 08 0E 4E 01 4B 00 06  .e...g..U..N.K..
    02 01 00 05 00 00 00 9D 00 04 62 67 30 32 01 31  ..........bg02.1
    00 04 42 47 30 32            ..BG02


    data: bg02-07778u3le@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:27 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 56 08 E5 88  ............V...
    01 C9 00 04 00 00 00 00          ........


    data: 1 groudId:0 itemId:28 classId:38

    01 6B 00 29 3C 68 74 6D 6C 3E 3C 62 6F 64 79 3E  .k.)<html><body>
    41 62 6F 75 74 20 51 41 20 4E 69 6E 6A 61 20 3C  About QA Ninja <
    2F 62 6F 64 79 3E 3C 2F 68 74 6D 6C 3E     /body></html>


    data: devblast2-0ugeo2oi9@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:29 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 56 08 E2 17          ....V...


    data: prdpbgt-0v6amoovg@groupchat.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:30 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 56 08 E5 1B          ....V...


    data: shristivm groudId:0 itemId:31 classId:51

    01 C9 00 04 56 0A 0F 20 01 31 00 0A 53 68 72 69  ....V.. .1..Shri
    73 74 69 20 56 4D            sti VM


    data: shristi01 groudId:0 itemId:32 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 31 00 09 53 68 72 69  .........1..Shri
    73 74 69 20 42             sti B


    data: 2frndgroupchat-0fokjutmn@groupchat.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:33 classId:28

    00 65 00 08 70 72 65 73 65 6E 71 61 00 67 00 04  .e..presenqa.g..
    56 0D 2C A1 01 4B 00 06 02 01 00 05 00 00 00 9D  V.,..K..........
    00 0E 32 66 72 6E 64 67 72 6F 75 70 63 68 61 74  ..2frndgroupchat
    00 B0 00 09 50 72 65 73 65 6E 20 51 41 01 31 00  ....Presen QA.1.
    11 32 20 66 72 6E 64 20 67 72 6F 75 70 20 63 68  .2 frnd group ch
    61 74                at


    data: classId 40 groupdId:0 itemId:34 classId:40

    data: ptgrp-0sj27uill@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:35 classId:28

    00 65 00 00 00 67 00 04 56 01 38 AF 01 4B 00 06  .e...g..V.8..K..
    02 01 00 05 00 00 00 9D 00 05 70 74 67 72 70 01  ..........ptgrp.
    31 00 05 50 54 47 72 70          1..PTGrp


    data: prabhakarg groudId:0 itemId:36 classId:51

    01 C9 00 04 55 C9 A2 6F 01 C7 00 04 55 C9 A2 6F  ....U..o....U..o


    data: classId 21 groupdId:0 itemId:37 classId:21

    data: shristib groudId:0 itemId:38 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 55 E5 2B 14 01 31 00 04 5B 73 62 5D  ....U.+..1..[sb]


    data: ptgrp-0sj27uill@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:39 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 56 04 E1 E8          ....V...


    data: qaninjazz groudId:0 itemId:40 classId:51

    01 C9 00 04 56 02 8B CA 01 C7 00 04 56 02 8B CA  ....V.......V...


    data: testgrp-0ght4s3eq@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:41 classId:28

    00 65 00 00 00 67 00 04 56 02 91 FD 01 4B 00 06  .e...g..V....K..
    02 01 00 05 00 00 00 9D 00 07 74 65 73 74 67 72  ..........testgr
    70 01 31 00 07 54 65 73 74 47 72 70      p.1..TestGrp


    data: testgrp-0ght4s3eq@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:42 classId:51

    01 C9 00 04 00 00 00 00          ........


    data: 12345-0u9aki8gc@groupchat.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:43 classId:28

    00 9D 00 05 31 32 33 34 35 00 B0 00 09 50 72 65  ....12345....Pre
    73 65 6E 20 51 41 00 67 00 04 56 09 11 DD 01 4B  sen QA.g..V....K
    00 06 02 01 00 05 00 00 01 31 00 05 31 32 33 34  .........1..1234
    35                 5


    data: 12345-0u9aki8gc@groupchat.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:44 classId:51



    data: devzblastzgrp-05thou6b7@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:45 classId:28

    00 65 00 00 00 67 00 04 55 D2 D0 42 01 4B 00 06  .e...g..U..B.K..
    02 01 00 05 00 00 00 9D 00 0D 64 65 76 5F 62 6C  ..........dev_bl
    61 73 74 5F 67 72 70 01 31 00 16 44 65 76 5F 42  ast_grp.1..Dev_B
    6C 61 73 74 5B 61 62 63 5D 5F 47 72 70 28 3A 44  last[abc]_Grp(:D
    29                 )


    data: devzblastzgrp-05thou6b7@blast.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:46 classId:51

    01 C7 00 04 00 00 00 00 01 C8 00 04 00 00 00 00  ................
    01 C9 00 04 56 04 E1 26          ....V..&


    data: 2frndgroupchat-0fokjutmn@groupchat.aim.com groudId:0 itemId:47 classId:51


group: Buddies groupdId:1 itemId:0 classId:1

    buddy: yashbajra groudId:1 itemId:1066 classId:0

    buddy: ShristiB groudId:1 itemId:2165 classId:0

    buddy: Designers groudId:1 itemId:5050 classId:0

    buddy: QABuddies groudId:1 itemId:7165 classId:0

    buddy: SameerK groudId:1 itemId:9163 classId:0

    buddy: PrabhakarG groudId:1 itemId:10806 classId:0

    buddy: qaninjazz groudId:1 itemId:14826 classId:0

    buddy: PrabeshM groudId:1 itemId:18369 classId:0

    buddy: PMs groudId:1 itemId:20865 classId:0

    buddy: testuser@gmail.com groudId:1 itemId:21590 classId:0

    buddy: Developers groudId:1 itemId:24328 classId:0

    buddy: sovita.dahal@presensoft.com groudId:1 itemId:26002 classId:0

    buddy: shristi01 groudId:1 itemId:26093 classId:0

    buddy: NirajB groudId:1 itemId:26636 classId:0
group: Family groupdId:2 itemId:0 classId:1
group: Co-Workers groupdId:3 itemId:0 classId:1
group: 1234 groupdId:4 itemId:0 classId:1
group: TechVortex groupdId:5 itemId:0 classId:1
group: Recent Buddies groupdId:6 itemId:0 classId:1

    buddy: presenqa groudId:6 itemId:1 classId:0

    buddy: 100008207471955@facebook.aol groudId:6 itemId:2 classId:0

    buddy: shristivm groudId:6 itemId:3 classId:0
group: BG02 groupdId:7 itemId:0 classId:1
group: (DEV) groupdId:8 itemId:0 classId:1
group: prdpbgt groupdId:9 itemId:0 classId:1
group: 12345 groupdId:10 itemId:0 classId:1
group: PTGrp groupdId:11 itemId:0 classId:1
group: TestGrp groupdId:12 itemId:0 classId:1
group: 2 frnd group chat groupdId:13 itemId:0 classId:1
group: Dev_Blast[abc]_Grp(:D) groupdId:15 itemId:0 classId:1
```

Comment: Thanks Todd.
I will check all the options available in this forum.
I have added the link to feedbag file in my question.

Comment: Thanks Todd. We need to find out which buddies are in which group.

Comment: I've updated the code to call out groups and buddies,  It appears that buddy membership follows the previously listed group.   Not sure about the first set of buddies at the top when you run the code, perhaps those are in a special group - not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks Todd. I ran the code in my Windows 7 machine and it is not giving the same output as yours. Could you please tell me why the code not working at my end?

The output at my end:

sizeof feedbagstring 16
group: <unknown> a:0 b:0 c:1
name: <unknown> 0 1 5
name: 0 0 2 38
name: 1 0 3 20
name: prdpbgt-0v6amoovg@groupchat.aim.com 0 4 28
name: 1024 0 5 20
name: <unknown> 0 6 4
name: <unknown> 0 7 0
name: <unknown> 0 1792 0
name: <unknown> 0 7 0
name: <unknown> 0 1792 0
name: <unknown> 0 7 0
name: <unknown> 0 1792 0
name: <unknown> 0 7 0
name: <unknown> 0 1792 0

Comment: So it appears that fopen works a little differently on Windows, I added a "rb" to fopen so it is treated as a binary file (vs text, probably deals with CRLF differently).    After this change I was able to get the same output on Windows as on Mac.   I'll be updating this with more code later - I've figured out what some of the other data means from the linked archive.org link

Comment: I've updated the code that calls out the root group - which has tagged data about the buddy list and preferences, etc.   Haven't decoded the Hex data yet - but the buddies and groups are printed below.

Comment: thanks for the updated code. Now, it lists the buddies and groups. But still, it cannot find out members of all group. In the output section, we can see only the members of the group Recent Buddies groupdId:6. Is there any chance we can get members for all groups?
Would you suggest any other ways to find the members of the group in AIM except from decoding feedbag file?

Comment: By any chance are the missing buddies all members of the blast groups?  Those don't seem to have their members listed - I'm wondering if offline buddies are not sent? 

Looks like two Groups had buddies (Buddies, and Recent Buddies).   I would suspect to get a complete listing of buddies - you will need to get data that isn't written to disk.    Do you know the number of buddies you expect in these groups?

Comment: Do you need to do this for this single buddy list?  Do you have access to the accounts that you are trying to decode the buddy list?

Comment: I have added the update1 section in the question to answer your questions. Thanks.

Comment: Blast group members don't seem to be stored in the feedbag file - so you probably would have to look at some of the open source AIM protocol handlers to get a live look at the state of the buddy list (pidgin is one).  AOL used to have OpenAIM, but no longer supports 3rd party logins.     As for online/offline status of non-blast members - I suspect that may be included in the additional data related to the buddy (not decoded yet in my code).   If you are looking for a constantly updated state of the buddy list, the feedbag file probably isn't updated enough, think of it as cache, not a model.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's a bytecode produced by **Common Intermediate Language**.

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language#Generation you can reverse it using a tool called **ILDASM** -  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa309387(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: Feedbag file is not a dll or exe. I think, AOL AIM uses it to store IM Group information locally. However, I tried to open the file feedbag using ildasm but it cannot open it. It gives following error:

  File 'd:\test\feedbag' not found or not a PE file

Answer (score 1):

[This](ftp://mail.im.tku.edu.tw/Prof_Liang/%BC%C6%A6%EC%C5%B2%C3%D1/Volume%203%20(2006)/Supplement%201/Issue%204/Pages%20227-237.pdf) document talks about how easy it is

Comment: That document only says that the file contains the user’s AIM contacts. It doesn't say anything about the meaning of the non-ASCII information.

Comment: How far down to decode the file?  The document breaks it down to the overall structure and lists

Answer (score 0):

The document cited by @user2174714 shows a hex dump of such a file. One thing I can see is that the group names are preceded by two-byte int containing the length of the name.

```
00000040 FF 00 07 42 75 64 64 69 65 73 00 01 00 00 00 01 ÿ..Buddies......
00000050 00 00 00 06 46 61 6D 69 6C 79 00 02 00 00 00 01 ....Family......
00000060 00 00 00 0A 43 6F 2D 57 6F 72 6B 65 72 73 00 03 ....Co-Workers..
00000070 00 00 00 01 00 00 42 A1 43 87 ......B¡C‡
```